# How to access variables inside an object?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, tostring

I am creating an algorithm to fill up a train with animals based on their size and type.

Imagine an animal object in an animal class with a `type` and `size`.

```cs
/* 0 = Carnivore, Carnivores will eat other animals which are smaller or the same size.
 * 1 = Herbivore
 * Animal sizes 1, 3, 5 are currently available.
 * A trainwagon can fit a maximum of 10 points. The wagon needs to filled optimally.
 * A new wagon is added if there are still animals which need to board the train. 
 */

public Animal(int type, int size)
{
    this.type = type;
    this.size = size;
}
```

I need the value of an animal to sort them. So, I created an override ToString() method to get the value.

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    string animalInformation = type.ToString() + size.ToString();
    return animalInformation.ToString();
}
```

I currently solved it by separating the characters of the string and converting them back to integers.

```cs
int animalType = Convert.ToString(animalInformation[0]); 
int animalSize = Convert.ToString(animalInformation[1]);
```

**My question is:** Is there another technique to access the variables in the animal object, because the double conversion impacts the performance of my algorithm in a unneccesary way.

Comment: `int type` and `int size` begs so urgently to be modelled as enums.

Comment: Just make Type and Size public properties and access them

Comment: You can create a property for type and size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take another look at your constructor:

```
public Animal(int type, int size)
{
    this.type = type;
    this.size = size;
}
```

This means that `type` and `size` are data members of your `Animal` `class`, which means that any instance of `Animal` has a `type` or a `size`. `this.type` is not a variable, but rather a data member of an object, which is similar to a variable due to its changeability, but it's an inherent attribute of an object. If you do something like

```
Animal animal = new Animal(1, 1);
```

and then you cannot reach `animal.type`, that means that `animal.type` is not `public`, but rather `private` or `protected`. You would be able to reach it if it were `public`. However, don't change it to `public`, it's good if you protect your fields from some problematic accesses I'm not describing at this point. Instead, you can define getters, like

```
public int getType() {
    return this.type;
}

public int getSize() {
    return this.size;
}
```

or some readonly [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and get the values by these.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some detail not evident from the question, you should just create properties for the fields, i.e.

```
public readonly struct Animal
{
    public int Type { get; }
    public int Size { get; }

    public Animal(int type, int size)
    {
        Type = type;
        Size = size;
    }
}
```

Sorting can be done with linq. 'ThenBy(...)' is only needed if you need to sort by both properties:

```
var sortedAnimals = animals.OrderBy(animal => animal.Type).ThenBy(animal => animal.Size);
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you only want to allow some values for type and size, you should probably use [enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum). Or at least validate the arguments and throw an exception if the validation fails.